# Fill whitespace with Iframe(jsfiddle)

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to build a page that has a header and a left-sidebar, and has an iframe in the content area. I wan't the Iframe area to fill the whole content area(the whitespace), but cant seem to get it to work. I am looking for the IFrame to fit perfectly, meaning that it begins where the header and left menu edges end. I can only seem to get it to span from one side of the page to the other, or get it in the middle of the whitespace.

Can anyone help?

Here is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P9CH9/2/

When removing the `<div id="iframe-content">` it will span the iframe from one side of the page to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by manually adding the margin top and left to the iframe container and also set the Top, left, right, bottom to 0 as such:

```
.abs-frame-container {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin-left: 250px;
margin-top: 55px;
}
```

Here is the latest JFiddle, I added black to show where the iframe is since JsFiddle doesn't seem to allow Iframes. http://jsfiddle.net/P9CH9/4/

Answer (score 0):

You set width 100% for wrappend and fixed the menu, so the wrapper does not consider at all the menu and gets the full width of the screen

Main Modification :

```
.menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #202020;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 55px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2147483647;
}

.wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 55px;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

And this solution is responsive.

See : http://jsfiddle.net/joseapl/P9CH9/5/